# How is it possible to cancel a retrofit call from outside the respected thread?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, progressdialog, request-cancelling

I'm creating such an on-thread issue of retrofit:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mService.uploadFile(body)
                            .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(final Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                }
            }).start();
```

I need to cancel the `call` in `onResponse` from outside the `Thread` via a `progressDialog.setButton()`. How is this possible?

*Any help is Appreciated!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get instance of `mService.uploadFile(body)`. This is `retrofit2.Call<T>` interface with public method [`cancel()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#cancel--).

```
   ...{
    call = mService.uploadFile(body)
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
   ...
```

And use it like this

```
  void cancel() {
        if (!call.isCanceled && call.isExecuted) call.cancel()
    }
```

Also metohd [`enqueue(Callback<T> callback)`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-)

> Asynchronously send the request and notify callback of its response or if an error occurred talking to the server, creating the request, or processing the response.

You don't need to use `Thread()` to deal with it.

Comment: This was a help. Thanks!  . . . And what's the `socket closed` Toast for?